# Redirect User to Login Page When Token Session Expired - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-5.8

## I want

to redirect my user to the login screen when token session expired.

[image]

My API will return http_code `401` when that happens.

## I did

```
public static function get($url) {

    try {

        $token = Session::get('user')->token;

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer '.$token));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'php');

        $result   = curl_exec($ch);
        $info     = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);

        if($result['http_code'] == 401){

            $token = Session::get('user')->token;
            $user = User::where('token',$token)->first();
            $user->delete();

            Session::flush();
            Auth::logout();

            return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Token expired.');

        }

        return $result;

    } catch (ConnectException $e) {

        Logging::error($e);
        return null;
    }

    return json_decode($result->getBody(), TRUE);
}
```

## I got

[image]

How would one achive this in Laravel 5.8  ?

Comment: If `$data` contains the result of `Redirect::to()`, you won't be able to access `$data['status']`. Could you remove the `Redirect::to()`, return `$result` and add an `else` to your `services()` method that handles a redirect then? Generally, this is all handled automatically via middleware, but you seem to have a different approach to this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will check the auth.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return Redirect::to('/login'));
}
```